# How to filter the modules included in JetBrains "module dependency diagram"?

Tags: webstorm

JetBrains has nice [module dependency visualizer](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/module-dependency-diagram.html):

[image]

Is it possible to exclude certain modules from the diagram?

Large diagram become very cluttered - especially when all the *external* modules are visible (eg. the @angular*.ts modules in the example above)

To me it seems very weird to create such a feature with no filter functionality.. A simple regex-on-name filter would've been enough.

## Alternatives

I shopped around for other utils:

- https://github.com/pahen/madge
- https://github.com/auchenberg/dependo
- https://github.com/sverweij/dependency-cruiser

Are all quite decent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible currently, please vote for [WEB-35691](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-35691) and linked tickets to be notified on any progress with this feature

Comment: Thanks! Weird those tickets didn't show up when I googled :blush:. In the meantime I found a bunch of third party tools that have more functionality (see my edit)